# Import OpenAPI Document or JSON during Swagger Generation

Tags: c#, swagger, openapi, swashbuckle

I have a small program that takes in an assembly and produces all relevant `OpenApiDocument`.  Now, my question is, can this be imported into Swagger?  I know you can add filters for modifying the documents after they have been created, but I am wondering if you can give Swagger the documents and circumvent the auto-generation.

Inside of the `IDocumentFilter` it allows you to modify the `OpenApiDocument` that Swagger creates, but I would like to use my own `OpenApiDocument`.

```
  public interface IDocumentFilter
  {
      void Apply(OpenApiDocument swaggerDoc, DocumentFilterContext context);
  }
```

Here is where I want to configure Swagger to use the predefined `OpenApiDocument`:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
     services.AddSwaggerGen(setupAction => TODO);
 }

 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IApiVersionDescriptionProvider provider)
 {
 }
```

Here are the publicly available methods that I want to utilize in the API startup when configuring Swagger:

```
 public static IEnumerable<OpenApiDocument> CreateDocuments(this Assembly assembly, string title, string description, string name, string email)
 {
      return ControllerInfo.FindControllers(assembly)
          .GroupBy(controller => controller.Version)
          .OrderBy(group => group.Key)
          .Select(group => CreateDocument(group.Key, group, title, description, name, email));
 }

 public static string ToJson(this OpenApiDocument document)
 {
     using var outputString = new StringWriter();
     document.SerializeAsV3(new OpenApiJsonWriter(outputString));
     return outputString.ToString();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe through some trial and error I came to a working solution.

```
  public void ConfigureSwagger(IApplicationBuilder app)
  {
      const string swagger = "Swagger";

      var directory = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), swagger);

      Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);

      app.UseDefaultFiles().UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
      {
          FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(directory),
          RequestPath = $"/{swagger}"
      });

      app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
      {
          foreach (var document in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CreateDocuments("title", "description", "name", "email"))
          {
              var file = $"swagger{document.Info.Version}.json";
              File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(directory, file), document.ToJson());
              c.SwaggerEndpoint($"/{swagger}/{file}", $"{document.Info.Title} {document.Info.Version}");
          }
      });
  }
```